# Error Code 31 read RSS with NSXMLParser

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser

i'm getting this error as i read RSS beginning with  xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?
if i change like that xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" , no problem to read the same RSS.

Do i have to ?
1/ download from a server to a file
2/ read the encoding and replace it by UTF8
3/ parse the file...

or can i do something else BEFORE launching the parser to change encoding header ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

i had such a problem and spent a night searching/
if i understood all properly the only way to parse not utf-8 rss is to use libxml library.
You can google a lot of documentation